# Get max value of property in an array of objects / entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a list of entities:

```
array = (0 => entity1, 1=> entity2,..., n=>entityn);
```

Every entity has a property called:

```
$initializedLevel = new ArrayCollection(); 
//key for this ArrayCollection is a 'date', value is an integer (= the level)
```

Every entity has a method called

```
getInitializedLevel($date)
// returns the level (= integer) for a specific date.
```

How do I get the highest level for a given date?

Comment: Don't know you DB schema, but I think querying that database will be much faster than any PHP arrays/objects manipulation.

Comment: thanks but due to the highly dynamic nature of this kind of data it's not persisted

Answer (score 3):

I was seeking similar method, and finally do in manually. I

```
$date = new \Date("now");
$max = $array[0]->getInitializedLevel($date);

foreach ($array as $entity) {
    $current = $entity->getInitializedLevel($date);
    $max = $current > $max ? $current : $max;
};
```

You have searched valued in `$max` variable now.

Answer (score 0):

could be done with :

```
public function getMaxLevelForAGivenDate($date)
{

$levels = this->initializedLevel->map(function ($initialize) use ($date) {
            if($date == $initialize->getDate()) {
                 return $initialize->getLevel();
              }

        });

        return  max($levels->toArray());
}
```